# VS Code Terminal opens, then crashes and disappears after pressing kill button

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get this error after I clicked "Kill terminal" in VS Code:

"Unable to resolve your shell environment: Unexpected exit code from spawned shell (code null, signal SIGSEGV)"

[image]

Now my VSCode does this when I click on Terminal, New Terminal:
It opens the window for about one second and then crashes and disappears.

I already deleted the settings.json file because I found a post on a similar problem.
Unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 6):

Simply restart the computer solved the issue for me (MacOS)

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: not sure where should I hide my face!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I got the same message and was definitely struggling with the same Terminal crashing issue. What worked for me was [uninstalling](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall) VS Code, and then [downloading](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) it again.

I'm using macOS and surprisingly, all my extensions were still available in the reinstall. There's probably a more technical way of doing it but that worked for me so I hope that helps!

Comment: I also uninstalled VS Code multiple times. But that didn't seem to work. However everyone should try reinstalling VS Code first. Probably my way of uninstalling VS Code was inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If your .bashrc file is messed up then this happens. Alternatively you can create a new user on your remote machine and try connecting then this works.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. The issue was resolved for me after I updated VS Code.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32742567)