# VS Code integrated terminal exits with native exception (code 216)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

Every time I try to open the terminal in VSCode it immediately fails with this error:
[image: The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 216).]

I tried uninstalling re-installing vscode, and disabled all my extensions, but it still happens. There is nothing I've changed right before it started occurring.

Colleagues in my organization do not suffer from this so I don't know if it has something to do with our IT dept.

- the version of vscode I use is 1.70.0
- my default terminal is Powershell. It does work when changing the default terminal to CMD.exe

  - Opening Powershell on its own does work properly.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem. Here is the link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046348/vs-code-terminal-opens-then-crashes-and-disappears-after-pressing-kill-button So Maybe you could try to follow the official VS Code uninstalling procedure.

Comment: I uninstalled it exactly as described there and it didn't help. Also after deleting the extensions and settings folders

Comment: I had a very similar problem. I even reached out to Microsoft. After all I reinstalled my computer (macOS) in maybe 10 hours total, with everything in place again. But then it worked after formatting the hard drive.

Comment: Formatting a hard drive or reinstalling an OS is definitely not an acceptable solution. I have a lot installed and configured. Also I'm using windows and it's managed by my organization's IT dept.

Comment: I've checked with cmd.exe, and it works properly. Thank you for the advice, I'll edit the main question